# Sequence of i.i.d. random variables with common characteristic function $f(t)=e^{-t^2-\sqrt{|t|}}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_n $ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with common characteristic function $$f(t)=e^{-t^2-\sqrt{|t|}}$$

$a)$ Find real numbers $\eta_n$ such that $\frac {X_1+ X_2+\cdots+ X_n}{\eta_n}$ converges in distribution to a non- degenerate probability distribution as $n\to \infty$.

$b)$ What possible distributions can the limit have?

$c)$ Prove or disprove $E\{|X_1|\}$ is finite.

I am sorry that I have posted the question without any attempt. But I was not even able to start the solution.
Can you please provide me some hint or direction to work on.

Thanks